# init: Failed to spawn telnetd main process: unable to execute: No such file or directory

Tags: 14.04, boot, scripts

**kernel: [   43.208320] init: Failed to spawn telnetd main process: unable to execute: No such file or directory** I get this message several times at start up on Ubuntu 14.04. telnetd is a script which I can start:

```
# /etc/init.d/telnetd start
* Starting Telnet Daemon
```

The rights are:

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root 4309 Jan 11 14:27 /etc/init.d/telnet
```

I initialized the service with:

```
# update-rc.d telnetd start 25 2 3 4 5 . stop 80 0 1 6 .
 System start/stop links for /etc/init.d/telnetd already exist.
```

I checked in /etc/rcX the existence of the links. They are there, i.e.:

```
 # find /etc/rc* -name "*telnetd*" | xargs ls -l
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22 Jan 11 14:24 /etc/rc0.d/K99telnetd -> ../init.d/telnetd
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22 Jan 11 14:24 /etc/rc1.d/K99telnetd -> ../init.d/telnetd
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22 Jan 11 14:24 /etc/rc2.d/S01telnetd -> ../init.d/telnetd
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22 Jan 11 14:24 /etc/rc3.d/S01telnetd -> ../init.d/telnetd
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22 Jan 11 14:24 /etc/rc4.d/S01telnetd -> ../init.d/telnetd
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22 Jan 11 14:24 /etc/rc5.d/S01telnetd -> ../init.d/telnetd
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22 Jan 11 14:24 /etc/rc6.d/K99telnetd -> ../init.d/telnetd
```

etc, init.d and rcX are owned by root root.

I checked the conf file:

```
# init-checkconf /etc/init/telnetd.conf
File /etc/init/telnetd.conf: syntax ok
```

I removed in (re)installed the sevice. No change.

I don’t understand the error message “No such file or directory” and why the script isn’t staring when booting.

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: Does the telnetd init script contain any relative paths?

Comment: There is something like this: [ -r /etc/default/$NAME ] && . /etc/default/$NAME (what does the point mean?).

Comment: `.` is an abbreviation for the builtin command `source` of all POSIX-compiant shells, e.g. bash. As long as the script is executed by a POSIX shell, this is no problem. Just check that the sourced file(s) is/are ok too.

Comment: Thanks! Your way of thinking was right. One variable wasn't set which should have been present in $NAME. I edited $NAME and it works. This is the reason for the error "file not found" (a little bit misleading but anyway!).

Comment: Please post this (in a more elaborate way) as an answer and mark it as accepted in 2 days.

Comment: It works. In the script was a file which didn't exist and it was checked by: [ -r /etc/default/$NAME ] && . /etc/default/$NAME. This command generated the error message. Thanks again for your help

Comment: Please post this as an answer, down below at the "Answer my question" button, and then mark your answer as accepted.